# what can we conclude about the sets A and B? Justify your answer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $|A \times B| = |A|$, what can we conclude about the sets A and B? Justify your answer.

$A \times B =A$  if and only if $A = \emptyset$ but what about the cardinality?

Comment: if $B$ is empty, then $A \times B$ is also empty, so think a bit more.

Comment: **Hint:** For finite sets you have $|A\times B|  = |A|\times |B|$.

Comment: As an aside, what you say in your post is incorrect.  The corrected statement is $A\times B = A$ if and only if $A$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give it away because this should only need a couple of hints.

First, suppose $A$ is finite and non-empty. Then can $B$ be infinite, or must it also be finite? If $B$ is also finite, then what must its cardinality be in this case?

What happens if $A$ is empty?

Next, consider the case when $A$ is infinite. You should now consider the cases $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|A| \geq |B|$. This should then cover all possible cases.

Comment: This is my final answer: $|A \times B| = |A|$ is true for the following


$1.$ $|A| = \emptyset$ then $|B|$ is anything.

$2.$ $|A|$ is finite. Then $|B| = 1$

$3.$ $|A|$ is countably infinite. Then $|B| > 0$, and is either finite or countably infinite

$4.$ $|A|$ is uncountable. Then $|B| > 0$, and is finite, countably infinite, or uncountable. Covered them all?

Answer (score 0):

A is empty or B is singleton or A is infinite and
cardinality B <= cardinality A.  Proof left for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I present hints so that you can prove these results by yourself.

1. $A$ is finite

   - $B$ is finite

Hint: $|A\times B|=|A|\times|B|$ for any finite sets $A,B$.

- $B$ is infinite

Then $|A|<|B|=|\{0\}\times B|\le |A\times B|$.

Hence $|A|<|A\times B|$.

2. $A$ is infinite

   - $|B|=0$

Then $|A\times B|=0<|A|$.

- $0< |B|\le|A|$

Then $|A|=|A\times \{0\}|\le |A\times B|\le |A\times A|=|A|$. Hence $|A\times B|=|A|$.

Hint: Assuming Axiom of Choice, $|A\times A|=|A|$ for any infinite set $A$.

- $|A|<|B|$

Then $|B|=|\{0\}\times B|\le|A\times B|\le |B\times B|=|B|$.

Hence $|A\times B|=|B|>|A|$.

Hint: Assuming Axiom of Choice, $|B\times B|=|B|$ for any infinite set $B$.